# Windows Phone 8.1 Media Element hide control buttons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

As I understood, I cannot customize the controls of Media Element, but du I have an option to hide or show some of them? For instance - I want to hide the zoom button.

The only option that I see is only to set the whole controls colection as visible and collapses.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Media Element doesn't have an option to hide some controls instead it have options to hide the whole control bar by setting property **AreTransportControlsEnabled** to true or false.
You can create the custom controls for Media Element instead of using default Controls of Media Element.

Comment: That's the problem, I cannot create custom controls for MeidaElement on Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Why you cannot create the custom controls.Just use **Slider control** for seeking and showing progress and pause,play and stop buttons.

Comment: Well, yeah I can do that. But I cannot use those controls when the MediaElement is in FullScreen.